# Scroll button to position when page scroll hits position

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So basically... as I scroll down a page, when it hits a certain point on the scroll, I want my button to scroll down the page to the bottom. Here is what I have so far.

I know the detection of when to do the action works because un-commenting out the alert works at the correct position. I need help with the button being scrolled down.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var height = $(window).scrollTop();

            if(height  > 1000) {
                //alert("hit part of page i want... works!");
                $('#<%= btnFinish.ClientID %>').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 500);

            }
        });
```

**EDIT:** HOW TO DO:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var d;
        var i;
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var docHeight = $(document).height()
        var obj = $('#<%= btnFinish.ClientID %>');
        var bottom = obj.position().top + obj.height();
        if (top + windowHeight == docHeight && bottom <= 800) {

            d = 0;
            for(i = 410; i>=85; i=i-.1){ 
                d  += .15;
                (function(ii,dd){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#<%= btnFinish.ClientID %>').css({ bottom: ii, right: 460 });
                    }, dd);    
                })(i,d);
            }

        } else if (top == 0 && bottom >= 801) {

            d = 0;
            for(i = 85; i<=410; i=i+.1){ 
                d  += .15;
                (function(ii,dd){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#<%= btnFinish.ClientID %>').css({ bottom: ii, right: 460 });
                    }, dd);    
                })(i,d);

            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            var d;
            var i;
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var docHeight = $(document).height()
            var obj = $('#<%= btnFinish.ClientID %>');
            var bottom = obj.position().top + obj.height();
            if (top + windowHeight == docHeight && bottom <= 800) {

                d = 0;
                for(i = 410; i>=85; i=i-.1){ 
                    d  += .15;
                    (function(ii,dd){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#<%= btnFinish.ClientID %>').css({ bottom: ii, right: 460 });
                        }, dd);    
                    })(i,d);
                }

            } else if (top == 0 && bottom >= 801) {

                d = 0;
                for(i = 85; i<=410; i=i+.1){ 
                    d  += .15;
                    (function(ii,dd){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#<%= btnFinish.ClientID %>').css({ bottom: ii, right: 460 });
                        }, dd);    
                    })(i,d);

                }

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix its position with CSS style.
style="position: fixed; bottom: 10px; right: 10px;"

And if you want to make it display after specific scroll then just show/hide that button after some scroll as per your convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `transition`:

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( window ).scroll( function () {
        var height = $( window ).scrollTop();

        if ( height < 500 ) {}
        if ( height > 1000 ) {
            $('#test').css({ bottom: 10, right: 10 });
        } else {
            $('#test').css({ bottom: 170, right: 10 });
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 2000px
}
#test {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 170px;
  right: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
     -moz-transition: all 1s;
       -o-transition: all 1s;
          transition: all 1s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="test">Button</button>
```